# How to get the tokens out of a text file and put it into a 2-D matrix?

Tags: c++, string, vector, matrix, text-files

I am running into an error that I do not know how to fix in a program about reading a text file and putting the tokens into a multidimensional vector.

My error is : 
char *token
Error: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char".

The codes are :

```
    std::vector< vector <std::string> > my_matrix(10, vector <std::string>(10));

    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("class_data.txt", ios_base::in);
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (myReadFile >> output) {
            myReadFile >> output;

            char* token = NULL;
            char* context = NULL;
            char delims[] = " ,\t\n";

            token = strtok_s(output, delims, &context);

            while (token != NULL)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                        my_matrix[i][j].push_back(token);
                        token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The task would be to get the tokens out of the text file and put them nicely into a 2-Dimensional vector of strings (10x10 matrix).
When I want to push_back the tokens into the 2D matrix, char* token is incompatible with the expression.
Could anyone help me fix the char* token error ?

P.S Sorry if I do not have the best professional codes, but I am a beginner in C++ and I did not take any University level programming courses.

Comment: Can you paste the info and student class ?

Comment: Don't do `while (!myReadFile.eof())`, it will not work as you expect it to. The reason is that the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of the file. Instead I suggest you do `while (myReadFile >> output)`.

Comment: I also suggest you read about [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream). And of course [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I will try your suggestions ...@ Mohan Kumar I do not have a student and info class...I just wanted to have a vector of students and a vector of info ... but probably I was wrong on doing that

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I edited my codes with your suggestion and I posted the updated version, but I still have the same error. Do you have any idea about the char* token issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the cause of your error.

```
my_matrix[i][j].push_back(token);
```

Change it to

```
my_matrix[i][j].push_back(*token);
```

you should be fine. Your `my_matrix` holds vector of vector of strings whereas the `token` is a char pointer.

Comment: Thank you. It works, I did not know that it needed a * at the push_back.

Comment: * will extract the value of the char pointer and string constructor accepts char, so all in all you can create a string with a character and not with a char pointer.